# ¿Que requisitos se deben considerar para ejecutar la version Trial de Genexus 18?

Tags: genexus, ssl, genexus18

Estoy ejecutando la versión Trial de Genexus 18, sin embargo, el compilar la solución, me muestra un error:

Internal error: Function call failed (A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - El cliente y el servidor no pueden comunicarse, ya que no poseen un algoritmo com£n.))
The reorganization process was not successfully completed.
Failed: Reorganization
error: Error in reorganization
Failed: Run Developer Menu

Estoy corriendo la aplicación en Windows 11 Pro (22H2), con una BD SQL.

Comment: Hola! ¿Qué es una BD SQL? Querrás decir SQL Server? SQL es un lenguaje, por si acaso. Qué versión de SQL Server? Será que necesitas revisar la encripción de la conexión a la BD?

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.